# How can I change giving text format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a text like this`'?category=1,2&brand=1'` how can I change this text into this
`'?categories[]=1&categories[]=2&brands[]=1'` ?

Answer (score 0):

pass parameter like: `?category=[1,2]&brand=1`

get using : `JSON.parse();`

Comment: I guess I need string.split() but can not achive the result yet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript
might help... ( find a better answer ).. happy coding...

Comment: did not help. Thanks anyway